# using javascript to output html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, bookmarklet

I have a javascript link that references another .js file. I've been trying to output an image (for testing purposes), but I'm not sure what is the correct way to go about this.

```
    alert("beginning");
    //var link = $("<a href='http://juixe.com'>Hello, <b>World</b>!</a>");
    //$('body').append(link);
    //document.write("hi");
    //document.write("<div><img src='http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/xqC6Iy5mOLb_8mwMKGv8_w/l.jpg' /></div>");
    alert("before function");
(function(){



    alert("middle");
    var links = $("<a href='http://juixe.com'>Hello, <b>World</b>!</a>");
    $('body').append(links);
    alert("after middle");
    //alert($("img").attr("id"));
    document.write("hi");
    document.write("<div><img src='http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/xqC6Iy5mOLb_8mwMKGv8_w/l.jpg' /></div>");

    alert("end");
}());
```

I was able to alert beginning, all the way to middle. It seems like `var links` doesn't work. I'm trying to use HTML inside this `.js` file. Essentially, I want to be able to do some modal window, but I'm trying to output images for testing purposes right now.

Also, is this the correct way for jquery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a strange mix. Jquery code almost always needs to run after the page has loaded whereas `document.write` can never be used after the page has loaded.

You are incorrectly wrapping your jQuery in an immediate executing function. The proper wrap for jQuery is within :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* html of page exists now, run jQuery here */
});// notice no extra "()" after close brace as you have
```

or the shorthand version that does same thing:

```
$(function(){
  /*html of page exists now, run jQuery here */
});// notice no extra "()" after close brace  as you have
```

If you change all of your `document.write` to `$('body').append(/* your content*/)` and place all your code inside the above wrappers you will have much better success.

There is a wealth of information within the jQuery documentation and API. A good start point with more detail about the wrapping I've shown can be found here:  http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: "document.write can never be used after the page has loaded". i just tried it in console, looks like it can be used but replaces whole page :)

Comment: just read this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write It shows an example which replaces page with document.write after page load. Just went curious on the your comment ;)

Comment: @sabithpocker  yes, I understand, but from all practical standpoints of beginner level javascript in context of OP's situation and to avoid writing a book as a response... there is limted use for it...*especially* trying to mix with jQuery

Comment: yes sure, sorry for going offtopic, it just happened that i didnt knew how document.write it works :)

Comment: I figured out what was really needed. I had to somehow import jquery into the page so this works, but you helped me understand my mix up,

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is addressed in the other answer.  You are improperly wrapping JQUery so essentially JQuery is not ready to be executed when it reaches your `append` statement.

It is unnecessary to wrap your html in a JQuery object (in this case):

```
var links = "<a href='http://juixe.com'>Hello, <b>World</b>!</a>";
$('body').append(links);
```

or simply:

```
$('body').append("<a href='http://juixe.com'>Hello, <b>World</b>!</a>");
```

In terms of best practice, using `append`, `appendTo` or `prepend` are good options depending on the context.  You could also use:

```
$("body").html("/*Your HTML here*/")
```

At the end of the day you have many options but avoid `document.write` at all cost.  The non-JQuery approach would be to use `.innerHTML` with a DOM element.  This is also a good approach in the absence of JQuery.

Comment: actually nothing wrong with wrapping `links` html in jQuery if you want to attach events or data before appending. I realize that's not what OP was doing it for and in his case is extra function call...but it works all the same

Comment: Your right, the issue is what you said about improperly wrapping the JQuery code, I will edit my post.

Comment: And for the grammar police, I noticed my your - you're usage mistake to late to make an edit.